# WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

**Python**
Dataset problem in last train step
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 2000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=32,
                                            class_mode='binary')

classifer.fit_generator(training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch=(8000),
                        epochs=25,`enter code here`
                        validation_data=test_set,
                        validation_steps=2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have code

```
classifer.fit_generator(training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch=(8000),
                        epochs=25,`enter code here`
                        validation_data=test_set,
                        validation_steps=2000)
```

the entry '`enter code here`' doesn't belong in model.fit_generator. Also .fit_generator is depreciated just use .fit. You do not need to specify steps_per_epoch or validation_steps in .fit. It will internally calculate them. However if you wish to specify them then use code

```
steps_per_epoch= total images in trainset//batch_size
```

For the validation steps you can use a similar code, however if you want to go through the validation set exactly once per epoch then use this code

```
length=total number of images in test set
valid_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=80],reverse=True)[0]  
validation_steps=int(length/test_batch_size)
```

use valid_batch_size as the batch size in your test_datagen. What the code does is determine the batch size and steps such that
valid_batch_size * validation_steps = total number of images in test set.